# Two-dimensional modelling of a flate-plate reactor

Tags: pde, matlab, finite-volume

[image]
I am trying to simulate the unsteady pollutant concentration along the reactor by solving the 2nd order PDE below with the stated BC and IC. which method is appropriate to solve convection-diffusion-reaction equation (unsteady state) using MATLAB. I solved the steady state using the function pdepe.
Note: I have no knowledge of finite volume/element methods to solving PDE's. I can't seem to recognize why the upwind scheme and second order central difference were used to discretize the convection and diffusion terms respectively. However,I have some knowledge about finite difference methods. Any sources I could read to help better my understand in order to handle the problem

```
% solve Ct=DCzz-vxCx

clear all

% parameters

D=9.1e-10; % Diffusion Coefficient for phenol in wastewater

vx=(0.05/10/3600)/(0.01*30*0.01)

% Domain and step

Lx=60

Lz=0.01

Nx=100

Nz=100

Nt=1000

dx=Lx/(Nx-1)

dz=Lz/(Nz-1)

% Satisfy Courant Number

C=0.05

ux=1

uz=1

dt=C/((ux/dx)+(uz/dx))

% Field Variables

Cn=ones(Nz,Nx)

x=linspace(0,Lx,Nx)

z=linspace(0,Lz,Nz)

[X,Z]=meshgrid(x,z)

% Initial conditions

Cn(:,:)=1

t=0

% loop

for n=1:Nt

Cc=Cn

for i=2:Nx-1
    for j=2:Nz-1
        Cn(j,i)=Cc(j,i)+(D*dt/(dz*dz))(Cc(j+1,i)-2*Cc(j,i)+Cc(j-1,i))-(vx*dt/dx)(Cc(j,i)-Cc(j,i-1))
    end
end

% Boundary conditions

Cn(1,:)=1

Cn(end,:)=1

Cn(:,1)=1

Cn(:, end)=Cn(:, end-1)

% Visualize

mesh(x,z,Cn); axis[0 Lx 0 Lz 0 Lz 0 1]

pause(0.01)

end
```

[image]

Comment: What is $z$ and what is $x$?

Comment: z-height of reactor x-length of reactor

Comment: And what is x? What is the geometry in x,z coordinates? Rectangular domain? It seems like we'd need more boundary conditions: boundary conditions on both zmin and zmax boundaries, and one on either xmin or xmax boundary.

Comment: Flat plate (rectangle), I am trying to find the appropriate dimensions that would satisfy the following condition (the pollutant in water degrades to 5 % of its initial value) at the outlet of the reactor. So I chose initially that my dimensions for x and z would be 60 m and 0.01 m respectively.

Comment: I don't think we have enough boundary conditions here, you need to set some BC on either xmin or xmax boundaries.  Anyway, what have you tried with your finite-difference method?

Comment: I didn't try to solve yet. What I did Instead was that I solved the equation under steady state conditions (dC/dt=0) using the function pdepe. I think another boundary condition I could impose the no-flux condition at the oultet dC/dx evaluated at x=60 is equal to zero

Comment: What I would recommend to do is discretize the equations in space by finite-difference and convert them to a system of 1st order ODE's in time, then use ode45 function in MATLAB to integrate those ODEs, that should work well for this problem.

Comment: @ Abmon98 Based on how the question has been edited in the last couple of days, it looks like you've made some progress there, so you can actually solve it now. What I suggest is you put for now the same boundary conditions $C=C_0$ on all boundaries, and see how you can implement time integration. You may find it useful reading examples available online, e.g., https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/385930-from-ode45-ode-to-pde. Also this one seems to be pretty good: https://www.math.tamu.edu/~phoward/m401/pdemat.pdf

Comment: I set the boundary conditions to the initial concentration, C0 and the no flux condition at the end of reactor length dC/dx=0 at x=60. I wrote the code to solve the equation however I faced 'parse error'  when I ran the code. Thank you Maxim for being a big help

Comment: The code seems to be fine overall, note that the way you do time integration the time step has to be very small, otherwise it would go unstable. But this is a fine way to do it for now, just to learn a couple of things. To locate the cause of the parse error I suggest commenting out some lines in the code until the parse error message is gone.

Comment: I realised that I forgot to put a multiply sign in the code (for loops) and thats whats causing the parse errors. However, the resulting plot (a horizontal plane cn=1) is not representative of what's expected to happen in reality.

Comment: Can you show the plot?

Comment: Also, what is vx value? Is it positive or negative? Are you familiar with upwind for convection? Is should be used here. Try instead of Cc(j,i+1)-Cc(j,i) use Cc(j,i)-Cc(j,i-1)

Comment: Is x the first coordinate? Then i should be the first index.

Comment: vx is a positive value, I am aware vaguely that convection term is represented by upwind schemes. I did ran the code it resulted in exactly the same plot

Comment: Try to comment out the convective term, keep only diffusion for now and see what happens.

Comment: When I tried to code without the convective term, the resulting plot is a horizontal line c=1

Comment: That's good, C=1 is a solution for those boundary conditions used. Now try to set a different boundary condition value on zmin or zmax, and see what happens. You should see time evolution of the profile C(z).